# Building primitive FGMOSFET for educational purposes

Tags: mosfet, flash, diy

To illustrate how flash memory works, I thought to build a primitive FGMOSFET and show that it stores a single bit of information (charged, uncharged).

It would require a high voltage to charge, it could be unreliable and leak current, but it would show the basic idea, and I could disconnect and reconnect it, and show with a multimeter that it remains charged or uncharged.

Is that viable?

How would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These FETs rely on tunneling.

To deposit charge into a bit, the insulation must be very thin, so under the stresses of high_voltage, the probability of electron movement becomes high/certain.

And afterward, with "normal" operating voltage, the probability of electron escaping becomes near zero, so the "bit" remains charged.

Thus you need to build a system with extremely thin insulation, that is of very high quality, very pure.

And with those skills, semiconductor fabs will want to hire you.

Comment: I was going to say it's easy- Start by building a semiconductor fab, pulling some pure silicon ingots, sawing into wafers, make a mask set, process the wafers, singulate, package, and done!

Comment: What I had in mind is to make a thicker insulation, but to use much higher voltage to make electron escape (I might be talking nonsense, but that's what I had in mind).

It wouldn't be usable, but it would demonstrate the technique.

Comment: @JohnD I seem to remember seeing silicon wafers for sale somewhere for only 3-digit prices.

Comment: @user253751 Sure, but that violates the DIY spirit of the question.

Comment: Making your own MOSFET on a silicion wafer you bought still counts as making your own MOSFET.